# Automatically set the scroll to end of file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I wasn't sure if this was possible or not... I have a couple of live error logs displaying to the user, I would like to place the scroll bar at the end of the file so they can see the last entry (most current) entry in the log.

Is this possible? And if so how would I go about doing this?

I figured it would just be a nice feature to have.

Comment: yes that is possible. besides, why can you not `order by date desc`??

Comment: Which *scroll bar*? You are using Notepad to view logs? Or you are using some control? What type of application you have - desktop, mobile, web? Show code you have to display log

Comment: Is this in a web or desktop application? What UI framework are you using (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC)? What are the log entries coming from (an application you control, or something else)?

Comment: @RichardEverett  am using WPF. the logs are text files loaded to a rich text box.

Comment: Could your users just use an off-the-shelf product like [BareTail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/). This has the added benefits of supporting multiple files and line coloring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that this is winforms and you are using TextBox to show your logs

```
void ScrollToBottom()
{
   txtLogEntries.SelectionStart = txtLogEntries.Text.Length;
   txtLogEntries.ScrollToCaret();
}
```